# Can't invoke the protected method in StAXOMBuilder() class

Tags: java, dom, w3c, axiom

I want to create w3c Document using StAXOMBuilder class in Axiom. And there is a method which can be used to achieve that task.

```
   OMElement documentElement = new StAXOMBuilder("resources/test.xml").getDocumentElement();
   XMLStreamReader llomReader = documentElement.getXMLStreamReader();
   OMFactory doomFactory = DOOMAbstractFactory.getOMFactory();
   StAXOMBuilder doomBuilder = new StAXOMBuilder(doomFactory, llomReader);

  Document doc = doomBuilder.createDocument();
```

createDocument method is available in [STAXOMBuilder Class](http://people.apache.org/~veithen/axiom/apidocs/org/apache/axiom/om/impl/builder/StAXOMBuilder.html) as a protected method. But when invoked it gives the error "The method createDocument() is undefined for the type StAXOMBuilder "

How to fix this?

Comment: Be sure that you are not typing createDocument() as creatDocument()

Comment: It seems to be that even http://people.apache.org/~veithen/axiom/apidocs/org/apache/axiom/om/impl/builder/StAXOMBuilder.html 
says that the createDocument is protected not private http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/branches/carbon/3.0.0/dependencies/axiom/modules/axiom-api/src/main/java/org/apache/axiom/om/impl/builder/StAXOMBuilder.java
suggests other wise. In the implentation of the class StAXOMBuilder createDocument method is declared private

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to create a DOM `Document` instance with Axiom is as follows. First, use `OMAbstractFactory#getMetaFactory(String)` to get an `OMMetaFactory` for the Axiom implementation that supports DOM. You do that by passing `OMAbstractFactory.FEATURE_DOM` to that method. You then have two possibilities:

1. Cast the `OMMetaFactory` to `DOMMetaFactory` and use the JAXP/DOM compatible methods defined by that interface.
2. Use the Axiom API to create an `OMDocument` and cast it to a `Document`. In particular, if you want to parse an existing document, use one of the methods in `OMXMLBuilderFactory` that takes an `OMMetaFactory` or `OMFactory` argument so that Axiom will use the DOM compatible implementation retrieved earlier.

Note that `DOOMAbstractFactory` is deprecated and that `StAXOMBuilder` is considered an internal implementation class (as the package name `org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder` implies) that should not be used directly.

Answer (score 3):

Following method worked for me. Thanks to Andreas.

```
     OMMetaFactory omMetaFactory = OMAbstractFactory.getMetaFactory(OMAbstractFactory.FEATURE_DOM);
     OMFactory omFac = omMetaFactory.getOMFactory();
     OMXMLParserWrapper wrapper = OMXMLBuilderFactory.createOMBuilder(omFac, new FileInputStream("resources/test.xml")) ;
     Document doc = (Document) wrapper.getDocument();
```

Answer (score 1):

To be able to invoke a `protected` method of a class, your class should either subclass `StAXOMBuilder` or be in the same package.

Comment: I've imported that class                                              import org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder;

are you suggesting extending that class? Becuase it doesn't work too

Comment: You are importing it, it is not in the same package with your class. The only way for you to extend the 'StAXOMBuilder' class.

Comment: I've extended but it yet it tells that "The method createDocument() from the type StAXOMBuilder is not visible "

Comment: It is probably not protected but private. Here is the StAXOMBuilder.java and createDocument() is private.
http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/branches/carbon/3.0.0/dependencies/axiom/modules/axiom-api/src/main/java/org/apache/axiom/om/impl/builder/StAXOMBuilder.java

Comment: http://people.apache.org/~veithen/axiom/apidocs/org/apache/axiom/om/impl/builder/StAXOMBuilder.html Says other wise. That was the confution.

So aren't there any way to create w3c Document using Axiom.

Comment: Be sure that you are not typing createDocument() as creatDocument(). Can you please check?

Comment: It's createDocument. No mistake. Doesn't work. So aren't there any way to create w3c Document using Axiom.